# Retrieving all of a user's subscribers with Facebook's APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

There doesn't seem to be any mention of this on facebook's API.
I found you can get a list of a user's subscribers with the graph API using /[user]/subscribers however this isn't returning the full list.
I've tried using the offset parameter but that's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=4%2Fsubscribers](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=4/subscribers)

I seem to get a big list.  At the bottom of the request, you can see paging options.

```
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/4/subscribers?format=json&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100003274909405"
  }
```

However, that link doesn't work.  And I get sporadic results with ?limit=X  https://graph.facebook.com/4/subscribers?format=json&limit=5  Sometimes will return 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 results, even though there are tonnes of them...

So I'd call it a bug.  You should report it to Facebook.

Comment: I reported it earlier.
Seems like there their graph API beta is even more buggy with subscribers as well.